# Field Selection on input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, event-handling

i have a problem with an input/selection field in PHP/HTML. If the user is writing a number in an input field the selection box should select the value automatically. I thought i could solve this with event listener onchange but im not sure how.

```
<select id="name" name="name" style="width: 154px"  /><br />
            <optgroup label="Department1">
            <option value="John">John</option>
            <option value="Max">Max</option>
            <option value="Test">Test</option>
             </optgroup>
            </select><br />
            </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number*: </td>
            <td>
            <input id="number" name="number" type="text" value="" maxlength="5" required style="width: 154px"/><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

Comment: What's the relationship between the number and the value that should be selected?

Comment: Do you want a pure javascript solution, or do you use a framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in codepen:

```
const  selectBoxField = document.getElementById('name')
const fieldNumber = document.getElementById('number')

fieldNumber.addEventListener('keyup', ({target}) => {
  selectBoxField.selectedIndex = target.value-1;
});
```

```
// variant with Id's
fieldNumber.addEventListener('keyup', ({target}) => {  
  const index = Array.from(selectBoxField).findIndex(option => option.id === target.value);
  selectBoxField.selectedIndex = index; 
});
```

see working example here https://codepen.io/kurkov87/pen/daJBpa?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you. Your code is almost what i need. Do you now how i can assign specific value to the selectbox names e.g. like if you write the number 12345 John will be selected and 13455 Max is selected?

Comment: @D2a you can take a look at this rewrite example https://codepen.io/kurkov87/pen/daJBpa?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

call the event in onblur.. i'm sure it will work

i'm giving you the quick example

```
    <select name="" id="asd">
        <option value="ashir">ashir</option>
        <option value="haroon">haroon</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" id="input_id" onblur="func()">
```

**JS CODE**

```
function func(){
        var input_id = document.getElementById('input_id').value;
        document.getElementById('asd').value = input_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing "onchange" event is not available on textfield in HTML instead u can use "onkeyup" event like this :-

```
document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keyup',(event) => {
    let num = parseInt(event.target.value);
    // write here the code to select the right option in drop down
});
```